# R identify missing rows from pre-specified sequence

Tags: r

I am a newer R convert and I have a large longitudinal dataset from an ongoing study. The data are organized one subject, one visit per row. The number of possible visits is conditional upon when each subject enrolled. I want to identify what visits are missing, or really, where there is a break in the expected sequence of visits. An example of the data might look like this:

```
  id  visit
1001     BL
1001 Week12
1001 Week24
1001 Week36
1002     BL
1002 Week12
1002 Week36
1002 Week48
1002 Week60
1002 Week72
1003     BL
1003 Week12
1003 Week24
```

The output I'm looking for would look ideally like this:

```
id   visit_missing
1002        Week24
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about how to identify missing cases? You might want to look into the substr() command to extract the last two characters of the visit variable.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me; as @Zslice said, please do try to explain well the output you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the instant responses. I've been lurking for over a year and finally got stumped enough to ask a question. So each subject is seen at exactly 12 week intervals. Baseline="BL" or Week0, 12 (weeks), 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, and finally 96 weeks. As human subjects do, they miss follow-up visits and I want to identify when this happened for each subject. But, the study is ongoing so some subjects will not and should not have some visits, but I want to know when they break the sequence. Better?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is a really terrible way to do it, but it's 3am and it's the best I could come up with right now.

```
## Creating the dataset
id <- c(rep(1001, 5), rep(1002, 6), rep(1003, 3))
visit <- c('BL', 'Week12', 'Week24', 'Week36', 'Week72', 'BL', 'Week12', 'Week36', 'Week48', 'Week60', 'Week72', 'BL', 'Week12', 'Week24')
data <- data.frame(id, visit)
data
## What the data looks like
     id visit
2  1001    12
3  1001    24
4  1001    36
5  1001    72
7  1002    12
8  1002    36
9  1002    48
10 1002    60
11 1002    72
13 1003    12
14 1003    24

## Removing all the text from the visit column and retaining only numbers
data$visit <- gsub('[^0-9]', '', data$visit)
data$visit <- as.numeric(data$visit)
data <- data[!is.na(data$visit), ]

missing <- data.frame()

## Checks if the difference between two consecutive entries in the visit column is more than 12 for the same id, and adds all the missing values to the missing data frame
for (i in 2:nrow(data)) {
  if ((data$visit[i] - data$visit[i - 1] > 12) & (data$id[i] == data$id[i - 1])) {
    x <- data$visit[i] - data$visit[i - 1]
    while (x > 12) {
      x <- x - 12
      missing <- rbind(missing, data.frame(data$id[i], data$visit[i] - x))
    }
  }
}

missing
## Output
      data.id.i. data.visit.i....x
1       1001                48
2       1001                60
3       1002                24
```

Comment: It works!! You may think it's terrible @Teja-K, but it def works. Thanks.